# how to assign click event to multiple buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the equivalent to the following statement in Javascript in a single line ?

```
$("#element1,#element2").on("click", runFunction);
```

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but, is there more than one line?

Comment: That is JQuery on click event for 2 elements, I want it to convert to Javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in plain old JavaScript? (Without jquery?)

Comment: @user3191903 : **JQuery is Javascript**

Comment: There is no equivalent in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var f = function() { /* Event handler */ },
    els = document.querySelector(/* selector */);
for(var i=0, l=els.length; i<l; ++i)
    els[i].addEventListener('click', f, false);
```

Just remove the line breaks and it will be in a single line.

But in ES6 you can get close:

```
for(var el of document.querySelector(/* selector */)) el.addEventListener('click', f, false);
```

Comment: "Just remove the line breaks and it will be in a single line." Exactly my thought... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply Do that by not keeping any space in your code

```
e1=document.getElementById('element1'),e2=document.getElementById('element2');if(addEventListener){e1.addEventListener('click',runFunction,false);e2.addEventListener('click',runFunction,false);}else{e1.attachEvent('click',runFunction);e2.attachEvent('click',runFunction);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, what you're really looking for is called:

### jQuery's Event Delegation [(see jQuery's `.on()` documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

*It's what **everyone** is looking for, even if they don't quite realize it yet ;)*

Don't bind your handlers onto your elements directly -- bind your handler to a parent element (perhaps <body>) instead, and use jQuery's event delegation model to specify a selector by which bubbled sub-events are filtered. In the following case, we place a click handler on the `<body>` which is specified to trigger for `a[href]` link clicks.

```
// Handles all link clicks under the <body> tag (superior methodology -- much optimum)
$('body').on('click','a[href]',function(jqEvent){
  var $a = $(this);
  console.log("Link Clicked:",$a.attr('href'));
});

// Direct binding, which is essentially what the original asker had (inferior)
$('a[href]','body').on('click',function(jqEvent){
  var $a = $(this);
  console.log("Link Clicked:",$a.attr('href'));
});
```